# How can i pass string data from one file to the other flutter

Tags: android, ios, string, flutter, dart

I want to pass the data of this string:  `String pathPDF = "assets/borst-oei.pdf";` to an other dart file named arbo.dart

The problem is that is don't know how I can do this with this: `GestureDetector( onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(PageTransition( child: PDFScreen(), type: PageTransitionType.fade)),`

i can't do this: `GestureDetector( onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(PageTransition( child: PDFScreen(pathPDF: ''),type: PageTransitionType.fade)),`
because it isn't defined then

this is the string: `String pathPDF = "assets/borst-oei.pdf";`

How can I fix this?

this is a bit of the code:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hetmaantje/utils1/colors.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import 'arbo.dart';
import 'assets.dart';

class oeiikgroei extends StatefulWidget {
  const oeiikgroei({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<oeiikgroei> createState() => _oeiikgroeiState();
}


  class _oeiikgroeiState extends State<oeiikgroei> {
    String pathPDF = "assets/borst-oei.pdf";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: const Text(
            "Oei ik groei",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
        hexStringToColor("no"),
    hexStringToColor("notshowing"),
    hexStringToColor("this is not an mistake"),
    hexStringToColor("#sorry")

    ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),


          child: Card(

            color: Colors.transparent,
           elevation: 0,

              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(


              ),

           child: ListView(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
             physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
             children: [
           Column(



           children: [

           SizedBox(

               width: double.infinity,
               child: Image.asset(Assets.imagesIcon17, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            SizedBox(
              height: Get.size.height * .02,
            ),]),

             ListTile(
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 1 , right: 4),
           tileColor: Colors.transparent,
             onTap: () {

               Navigator.of(context).push(PageTransition(
                   child: PDFScreen(),
                   type: PageTransitionType.fade));

             },
             textColor: Colors.white,
             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(

               side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3 ),
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
             ),
```

I have extended the PDFScreen now and it works, but i will use the way below instead.

Is there any preformence matters between the methodes?

Comment: then define it, show me a snippet for PDFScreen widegt and I will help you

Comment: i have defined it can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What isn't "defined then" ? The parameter to the PDFScreen or the String pathPDF itself?

Just add the parameter to the constructor of the widget named `PDFScreen` (if it is StatefulWidget that doesn't matter).

```
class PDFScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PDFScreen({Key? key, required this.pathPdf}) : super(key: key);
  final String pathPdf;
  ...
}
```

Then use it as:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
    PageTransition(
      child: PDFScreen(pathPDF: pathPDF),
      type: PageTransitionType.fade),
  ..
)
```

Comment: i have defined the string

Comment: The named parameter 'pathPDF' isn't defined.   this is the error

Comment: I understand. Well in that case do what I wrote. Present the code to the widget PDFScreen() if my suggestion didn't work.

Comment: it also works with the way you do it thank you very much. is there a difference between preformence or something with the way i wrote above and your way?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, because your way didn't work? So the best answer I can give you is probably: maybe.

Comment: Oke thank you very much i am using the way u wrote it now. I think that this is the best way

Answer (score 0):

Navigation from here with data

```
 GestureDetector(
 onTap: () {
   Navigator.push(
     context,
     MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: ((context) => PDFScreen(pathPDF: pathPDF)),
     ),
    );
  },
);
```

Get data in another file

```
class PDFScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PDFScreen({Key? key, required this.pathPdf}) : super(key: key);
  final String pathPdf;      
  // The rest of your code
}
```